# php/laravel: Creating chartdata, return 0 if no data is being submitted to database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, chart.js

I am trying to create a chart from data returned by a databse. The data is stored in a database and there can be multiple charts in this table. Identified by a unique value. (rigname)

```
array:102 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 2002
      "user_id" => "1"
      "rigname" => "home"
      "data" => "{"hashrate":12.364,"pool":"eu1.ethermine.org:4444","shares":{"valid":"2","invalid":"0"},"gpus":[{"temperature":"56","fanSpeed":"56","hashrates":12.364}]}"
      "created_at" => "2018-02-23 10:24:50"
      "updated_at" => "2018-02-23 10:24:50"
    ],
1 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 2019
      "user_id" => "1"
      "rigname" => "server"
      "data" => "{"hashrate":76.612,"pool":"eu1.ethermine.org:4444","shares":{"valid":"736","invalid":"2"},"gpus":[{"temperature":"65","fanSpeed":"67","hashrates":19.804},{"temp ▶"
      "created_at" => "2018-02-23 10:25:56"
      "updated_at" => "2018-02-23 10:25:56"
    ]
```

As you can see there are two possible charts according to the rigname. I want to display the hashrate value of the two rigs on a chart. This works, but, when one rig stops there is no data being submitted to the database from that rig.
The chart displays no 0 value for that rig, the last known data is being used. (duh)

I solved this by modifying my query like this:

```
$res[$value] = json_decode(MinerStatistics::where('rigname', $value)
            ->where('created_at','>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMinutes(20))
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get()
            ->toJson(), true
       );
```

Now when the rig is stopped and I query the database, I only get the data from the past x minutes. This is done in a foreach that builds a new multidimensional array with the data sorted per rigname.

This rises a new problem, when I restart the rig and it starts reporting to the database. The values on the chart continue not at the current timestamp, they continue where the rig has stopped. Normally I would compare the timestamp of the last reported data and the previous reported data with the data of the rig that is still running and return 0 every time a running rig reports, but they report different timestamps ( all within 8 sec of each other)

How can I modify the returned mysql data that I end up with something like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  "home" => array:150 [
      0 => array:6 [▼
        "id" => 2300
        "user_id" => "1"
        "rigname" => "home"
        "data" => "{"hashrate":12.359,"pool":"eu1.ethermine.org:4444","shares":{"valid":"5","invalid":"0"},"gpus":[{"temperature":"57","fanSpeed":"57","hashrates":12.359}]}"
        "created_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:42"
        "updated_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:42"
        ]
    1 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 2298
      "user_id" => "1"
      "rigname" => "home"
      "data" => "{"hashrate":12.367,"pool":"eu1.ethermine.org:4444","shares":{"valid":"5","invalid":"0"},"gpus":[{"temperature":"57","fanSpeed":"57","hashrates":12.367}]}"
      "created_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:34"
      "updated_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:34"
    ]
    2 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 2296
      "user_id" => "1"
      "rigname" => "home"
      "data" => "{"hashrate":12.367,"pool":"eu1.ethermine.org:4444","shares":{"valid":"5","invalid":"0"},"gpus":[{"temperature":"57","fanSpeed":"57","hashrates":12.367}]}"
      "created_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:26"
      "updated_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:26"
    ]

    ...
    Server stops, no data, should continue like this

    3 => [false] ,
    4 => [false] ,
    5 => [false] 
    ...
    rig reports again to the database

    36 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 2296
      "user_id" => "1"
      "rigname" => "home"
      "data" => "{"hashrate":12.367,"pool":"eu1.ethermine.org:4444","shares":{"valid":"5","invalid":"0"},"gpus":[{"temperature":"57","fanSpeed":"57","hashrates":12.367}]}"
      "created_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:26"
      "updated_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:26"
    ],
  ],
  "server" => array:150 [▼ // This keeps running, or visa versa
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 2301
      "user_id" => "1"
      "rigname" => "server"
      "data" => "{"hashrate":76.62,"pool":"eu1.ethermine.org:4444","shares":{"valid":"749","invalid":"2"},"gpus":[{"temperature":"64","fanSpeed":"67","hashrates":19.778},{"tempe ▶"
      "created_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:44"
      "updated_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:44"
    ]
    1 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 2299
      "user_id" => "1"
      "rigname" => "server"
      "data" => "{"hashrate":76.68,"pool":"eu1.ethermine.org:4444","shares":{"valid":"749","invalid":"2"},"gpus":[{"temperature":"64","fanSpeed":"65","hashrates":19.815},{"tempe ▶"
      "created_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:36"
      "updated_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:36"
    ]
    2 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 2297
      "user_id" => "1"
      "rigname" => "server"
      "data" => "{"hashrate":76.644,"pool":"eu1.ethermine.org:4444","shares":{"valid":"749","invalid":"2"},"gpus":[{"temperature":"64","fanSpeed":"65","hashrates":19.793},{"temp ▶"
      "created_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:28"
      "updated_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:28"
    ]
    3 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 2295
      "user_id" => "1"
      "rigname" => "server"
      "data" => "{"hashrate":76.105,"pool":"eu1.ethermine.org:4444","shares":{"valid":"749","invalid":"2"},"gpus":[{"temperature":"64","fanSpeed":"65","hashrates":19.793},{"temp ▶"
      "created_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:20"
      "updated_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:20"
    ]
    4 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 2293
      "user_id" => "1"
      "rigname" => "server"
      "data" => "{"hashrate":76.557,"pool":"eu1.ethermine.org:4444","shares":{"valid":"749","invalid":"2"},"gpus":[{"temperature":"64","fanSpeed":"65","hashrates":19.78},{"tempe ▶"
      "created_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:12"
      "updated_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:12"
    ]
    5 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 2291
      "user_id" => "1"
      "rigname" => "server"
      "data" => "{"hashrate":76.562,"pool":"eu1.ethermine.org:4444","shares":{"valid":"749","invalid":"2"},"gpus":[{"temperature":"64","fanSpeed":"65","hashrates":19.794},{"temp ▶"
      "created_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:04"
      "updated_at" => "2018-02-23 10:44:04"
    ]
  ]
]
```

The current code I have written:

```
public function index()
{
    // Get the statistics from the database reported by the miner
    // Group them by the rig name
    $stats = MinerStatistics::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('created_at','>=', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(20))
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->take(300)
        ->get()
        ->groupBy('rigname');

    // Get the rig names
    $rigs = (object) [];
    foreach($stats as $key => $value) {
        $rigs->$key = $key;
    }

    // For each rig, get the last known stats between now and 10 seconds ago
    $table = (object) [];
    foreach($rigs as $key => $value) {
        $tableData = $stats[$value]
            ->where('created_at','>=', Carbon::now()->subSeconds(10));

        if (isset($tableData[0]) && $tableData !== []) {
            $table->$key = (object) $tableData[0];
            $table->$key->data = json_decode($tableData[0]['data'], true);
        } 
    }

    return view('rigs', [
        'rigs' => $table,
        'chart' => $this->chart($stats)
    ]);
}

    public function chart($data) 
    {
        $p = [];
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $x = [];
            $time = [];
            foreach($value as $k => $v) {
                $time[] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $v['created_at'])->format('H:i:s');
                $x[] = json_decode($v['data'], true);
            }

            $hashrate = [];
            foreach($x as $k => $v){
                $hashrate[] = $v['hashrate'];
            }
            $p[$key] = [ 'time' => $time, 'hashrate' => $hashrate ];
        }

        $datasets = [];
        $n = 0;
        foreach($p as $key => $value) {
            $colors = [
                "0, 188, 212",
                "244, 67, 54",
                "255, 152, 0"
            ];

            $datasets[] = $this->chartData('Hashrate: ' . $key, array_reverse($value['hashrate']), $colors[$n++]);
        }
        dd($time);
        $chart = app()->chartjs
            ->name('lineChartTest')
            ->type('line')
            ->size(['width' => '100%', 'height' => '20%'])
            ->labels(array_reverse($time))
            ->datasets($datasets)
            ->optionsRaw("{ 
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        ticks: {
                            suggestedMin: 0,    // minimum will be 0, unless there is a lower value.
                            beginAtZero: true   // minimum value will be 0.
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }");

        return $chart;
    }

    public function chartData($label, $data, $color)
    {
        return [
            "label" => $label,
            'backgroundColor' => "rgba(" . $color . ", 0)",
            'borderColor' => "rgba(" . $color . ", 0.7)",
            "pointBorderColor" => "rgba(" . $color . ", 0, 0.7)",
            "pointBackgroundColor" => "rgba(" . $color . ", 0.7)",
            "pointHoverBackgroundColor" => "#fff",
            "pointHoverBorderColor" => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            'data' => $data,
        ];
    }
```

EDIT: I have found the answer, check below.

Comment: `json_decode( ... ->toJson(), true)`  why not use toArray()?

Comment: @Devon This is a quick sketch, json_decode was what first came to mind to do the job. toArray() is probably cleaner, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made an array `$timeLabels` this array contains timestamps from the current time till x minutes/hours ago in intervals of x minutes.

Then I loop over my rigs and compare the created_at with the values in the timeLabels. If it is in the same range (+/-10 sec) the data from the collection goes into an array with the timeLabel as key. When a timeLabel has no value, it gets 0 assigned as data. This actually works, but needs some tuning.

Full example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Rigs;

use Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\MinerStatistics;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class RigController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the rigs dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // Get the statistics from the database reported by the miner
        // Group them by the rig name
        $stats = MinerStatistics::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('created_at','>=', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(60))
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->take(300)
            ->get()
            ->groupBy('rigname');

        // Get the rig names
        $rigs = (object) [];
        foreach($stats as $key => $value) {
            $rigs->$key = $key;
        }

        // For each rig, get the last known stats between now and 10 seconds ago
        $table = (object) [];
        foreach($rigs as $key => $value) {
            $tableData = $stats[$value]
                ->where('created_at','>=', Carbon::now()->subSeconds(10));

            if (isset($tableData[0]) && $tableData !== []) {
                $table->$key = (object) $tableData[0];
                $table->$key->data = json_decode($tableData[0]['data'], true);
            } 
        }

        return view('rigs', [
            'rigs' => $table,
            'chart' => $this->chart($stats)
        ]);
    }

    public function chart($data) 
    {
        $start = Carbon::now('Europe/Brussels');
        $end = Carbon::now('Europe/Brussels')->subMinutes(60);
        $timeLabels = $this->createTimeRange($end, $start);
        $chartData = (object) [];
        // Go over each returned rig
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $arr = array(); // Create an empty array to store our results
            // Go over all our timeLabels
            foreach(array_reverse($timeLabels) as $t => $time) {
                // Create a range to match the incomming created_at and timeLabels
                // Needs finetuning!!
                $start = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $time)->subSeconds(30)->format('H:i:s');
                $end = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $time)->addSeconds(30)->format('H:i:s');

                foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                    // Transform created_at to the same format as $start and $end
                    $created = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $v['created_at'])->format('H:i:s');
                    if($created >= $start && $created <= $end) {
                        if(!isset($v->data['hashrate'])){
                            $hashrate_ = json_decode($v->data,true)['hashrate'];
                        } else {
                            $hashrate_ = $v->data['hashrate'];
                        }

                        $arr[$time] = $hashrate_;
                    } 
                }

                // If the set timeLabel has no value set to 0
                // Rig is not running...
                if (!isset($arr[$time])) {
                    $arr[$time] = '0';
                }

            }
            $chartData->$key = $arr;
        }

        $datasets = [];
        $n = 0;
        foreach($chartData as $key => $value) {
            $data = [];
            foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                $data[] = $v;
            }
            $colors = [
                "0, 188, 212",
                "244, 67, 54",
                "255, 152, 0"
            ];

            $datasets[] = $this->chartData('Hashrate: ' . $key, array_reverse($data), $colors[$n++]);
        }


        $chart = app()->chartjs
            ->name('lineChartTest')
            ->type('line')
            ->size(['width' => '100%', 'height' => '20%'])
            ->labels($timeLabels)
            ->datasets($datasets)
            ->optionsRaw("{ 
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        ticks: {
                            suggestedMin: 0,    // minimum will be 0, unless there is a lower value.
                            beginAtZero: true   // minimum value will be 0.
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }");

        return $chart;
    }

    public function chartData($label, $data, $color)
    {
        return [
            "label" => $label,
            'backgroundColor' => "rgba(" . $color . ", 0)",
            'borderColor' => "rgba(" . $color . ", 0.7)",
            "pointBorderColor" => "rgba(" . $color . ", 0, 0.7)",
            "pointBackgroundColor" => "rgba(" . $color . ", 0.7)",
            "pointHoverBackgroundColor" => "#fff",
            "pointHoverBorderColor" => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            'data' => $data,
        ];
    }

    private function createTimeRange($start, $end, $interval = '5 mins', $format = '24') {
        $startTime = strtotime($start); 
        $endTime   = strtotime($end);

        $returnTimeFormat = ($format == '12')?'g:i A':'G:i';

        $current   = time(); 
        $addTime   = strtotime('+'.$interval, $current); 
        $diff      = $addTime - $current;

        $times = array(); 
        while ($startTime < $endTime) { 
            $times[] = date($returnTimeFormat, $startTime); 
            $startTime += $diff; 
        } 
        $times[] = date($returnTimeFormat, $startTime); 
        return $times; 
    }
}
```

If I do it like this, I could create a dedicated class so I can reuse this logic. The data I get returned to pass to the charts is now formatted like this: (exactly what I needed)

```
{#3436 ▼
  +"home": array:13 [▼
    "17:47" => 13.44
    "17:42" => 13.417
    "17:37" => 13.439
    "17:32" => 13.436
    "17:27" => 13.438
    "17:22" => "0"
    "17:17" => "0"
    "17:12" => "0"
    "17:07" => "0"
    "17:02" => "0"
    "16:57" => "0"
    "16:52" => "0"
    "16:47" => "0"
  ]
  +"server": array:13 [▼
    "17:47" => "0"
    "17:42" => 76.373
    "17:37" => 76.514
    "17:32" => 76.565
    "17:27" => 76.486
    "17:22" => "0"
    "17:17" => "0"
    "17:12" => "0"
    "17:07" => "0"
    "17:02" => "0"
    "16:57" => "0"
    "16:52" => "0"
    "16:47" => "0"
  ]
}
```